# Multiple sites, multiple countries

Tags: plugins, multisite

we are currently working on our website relaunch.

Basically, the new website consists of three subsites (areas of business, all sites are differently styled, different theme etc.). Each of the three sites should be targeted to three countries. Thereby, there are only minor content differences between the country-specific versions (phone numbers etc., currency etc.).

To adress these country-specific content issues, we are planning to use a [plugin](https://de-ch.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-by-country/) for geo-targeted content. So basically, we have three wordpress sites and do not need separate installs for the three countries.

The domain structure should look like this in the end (example for country de):

- www.domain.com/de/site1
- www.domain.com/at/site1
- www.domain.com/ch/site1
- www.domain.com/de/site2
- www.domain.com/ch/site2
- www.domain.com/at/site2

and so on...

Based on my research, a multisite install of wordpress in combination with WPML would be the correct approach for this.

Is it possible to achieve a domain structure as shown above by using multisite and WPML?

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: hi, could you please accept the answer? @STATWORX

Answer (score 1):

Recently i saw this being used in [Gett.com](http://gett.com/):

every country has a small country code added to the address, and than lists the locations in which the service is available in this place. the site uses WPML (a friend of mine actually built it) so it's possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

gett.com is only one site for multiple countries:
gett.com/us
gett.com/ca
and so on

We have three sites
domain.com/de/site1
domain.com/de/site2
domain.com/de/site3
and so on

Any thoughts are appreciated :)

Comment: if that you can use wordpress's permalinks / htaccess rewrite to override the config. i don't have much experience with multisites but it seems as the right platform for this

Comment: have you tried it? i think that'll be your solution